# How to authenticate a web service that expects NTLM handshake for authorization using pre-generated ntlm hash?

Tags: c#, authentication, hash, single-sign-on, ntlm

I have a C# client that is invoking a web service. For authentication, it is currently using NetworkCredential(user, password, domain) object.
I don't want to hard code the password in code nor pass it as parameter to the application.
I like to save NTLM hash and use the hash to authenticate.

Like cntlm (http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/), I like to pregenerate password hash and use it later for authentication.

Is there a built C# NetworkCredential object that works with hashes?

Thanks